# how to show the bottom of div with scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a DIV with scroll that have a information from the mySQL.

this DIV supose to be a chat (like the facebook chat) and its refresh with ajax every some seconds.

i need that this DIV alwase will show me the information that in the bottom (like the facebook chat)

how i made it (keep the scroll down)?

```
<div style='width:100%; height:275px; bottom:25px; overflow-y:scroll;' id='aaa'>
  chat 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("your_div");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your div tag
set style as

```
style='width:100%; height:275px; bottom:25px; overflow-y:auto;'
```

when the new chat message appears the scroll bar of y-axis has been automatically drops